# Is this VBScript string comparison to the empty string redundant?

Tags: vbscript, mdt

I'm dealing with a collection of VBScript code (Microsoft Deployment Toolkit) and I frequently see the follow idiom when comparing a string to see if it has a given value:

```
If (oEnvironment.Item("IsOSUpgrade") <> "" and oEnvironment.Item("IsOSUpgrade") = "1") then
```

`oEnvironment.Item` is a property that I imagine could return null/nothing/empty (haven't wrapped my head fully around the subtle differences).

Does the first comparison serve any purpose? I'm guessing it does but don't understand what it would be. For surely if the the equality comparison returns True then the inequality comparison would as well, right? What am I missing? Something with null/nothing/empty?

Comment: Once you have found an answer which works for you, please click the tick next to that answer to accept it. This lets other people with your problem know which solution worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

**You're right**: if the second condition is true, the first will always be true. I think the first condition is there just for completeness and makes sure that `"IsOSUpgrade"` isn't empty/null.

Don't worry, you're not missing anything ;-)